# Why is this nullable type throwing an exception

Tags: c#, nullable

Say I have the following dictionary like so:

```
 public static Dictionary<Type, string> nullableTypeToStringMap = new Dictionary<Type, string>()
    {
        {typeof(bool?)    ,  "bool?"},   
        {typeof(byte?)    ,  "byte?"},   
        {typeof(sbyte?)   ,  "sbyte?"},  
        {typeof(char?)    ,  "char?"},    
        {typeof(decimal?) ,  "decimal?"},
        {typeof(double?)  ,  "double?"}, 
        {typeof(float?)   ,  "float?"},  
        {typeof(int?)     ,  "int?"},     
        {typeof(uint?)    ,  "uint?"},   
        {typeof(long?)    ,  "long?"},   
        {typeof(ulong?)   ,  "ulong?"},  
        {typeof(short?)   ,  "short?"},  
        {typeof(ushort?)  ,   "ushort?"}
    };
```

and say I have execute this line:

```
nullableTypeToStringMap [typeof(int?)];
```

I get the following exception: `The type initializer for 'DatabaseUtils.Utils.TypeMap' threw an exception.`

However, if I execute this line:

```
nullableTypeToStringMap [typeof(int)];
```

It works fine. Any idea why the nullable type is causing me issues?

Comment: Is there anything else that happens at type initialization time for `TypeMap`? Any other static fields, or a non-empty cctor?

Comment: I would guess  that where int? is you did not initialize it a null so therefore how can it be a nullable if you did int? myint = null  then check the type I bet it would not error..

Comment: Where do you execute `nullableTypeToStringMap [typeof(int?)];`? What is `DatabaseUtils.Utils.TypeMap`?

Comment: @Slaks The inner exception is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Are you sure it is related to that code? I receive no such exception on .Net 4.0.

Comment: I literally copy pasted your code into LINQPad (removed `private static`) and your code works fine... something else must be happening?

Comment: Other than the KeyNotFoundException, the above code seems to work fine. What exception is thrown? What's in `TypeMap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that your code is in an earlier static field initializer, so it's running before you assign `nullableTypeToStringMap`.
You need to order the static fields so that you don't use a field before initializing it.

Comment: What do your psychic debugging skills say about why `nullableTypeToStringMap [typeof(int)];` works?

Comment: So is it fair to close this question as "too localized"?

Comment: Your psychic debugging skills amaze me. I come from a java background where it does not matter the order you declare static variables. This was definitely a "gotcha". Thanks so much.

Comment: @user489041: How is that possible? AS far as I can tell, Java also executes initializers in declaration order.